# binary_search return always true c++

Tags: c++, syntax-error, binary-search

I'm stuck with this problem, I am dealing with vector of positions.
this vector is ordered with respect to the first component of the couple "position" in one case and with respect to the other one in the other case, in both cases, the other element of the couple stays constant.
So for example I have:

```
 1 1, 1 3, 1 7, 1 11  //second case
```

Now I want to use the binary_search algorithm in order to find if there exist a specific position in one of such vectors, but the answer is positive even if it shouldn't!

Here's my code

```
using namespace std;

class position{
     int r;
     int c;
public:
     position(int r=0, int c=0): r(r), c(c){
     };

position &operator=(position p);

int getr(){
    return r;
};
int getc(){
    return c;
};
friend bool operator>(const position &p, const position &q);
friend bool operator<(const position &p, const position &q);
friend bool operator==(const position &p, const position &q);

};

bool operator>(const position &p, const position &q);{
    return((p.r>q.r)&&(p.c>q.c));
};

bool operator<(const position &p, const position &q);{
    return q>p;
};

bool operator==(const position &p, const position &q);{
    return((p.r==q.r)&&(p.c==q.c));
};

 int main(){
 vector<position> R;

 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    R.push_back(position(1,2*i));

 for(int i=0;i<R.size();i++)
    cout<<R[i];
 cout<<endl;
 posizione a(1,7);

 cout<<binary_search(R.begin(),R.end(),a);

 }
```

Comment: Your example is _so close_ to compiling!  Get a working version up on a site like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) so that we can be more helpful.  Also, the STL asks for a *less than* operator overload, not the *greater than* you've provided.  This could be the reason, though I doubt it; we'll be able to find out if you post a working example.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, complete  and verifiable example as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

For example, this one is missing the code that populates 'v' and doesn't indicate how you are examining the result of binary_search.

Comment: Imagine you have the two points a=1,3 and b=1,7. Then a>b is false and b>a is false, using your > operator, therefore binary search assumes a==b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator >` does not guarantee strict ordering.  When dealing with comapring multiple member variables I find it best to use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).  The following should give you the correct results

```
bool  operator > (const position&p, const operator&q){
    return std::tie(p.x, p.y) > std::tie(q.x, q.y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- The STL asks for `operator<`, not `operator>`.  You should follow its example so you don't get any surprises when using other algorithms.
- Your comparison is incorrect, and will return false positives.  Although other answers correctly explain how to fix this, you should really be using `std::pair<int, int>` instead anyway.  It implements that and many more features for you.

---

```
using Position = std::pair<int, int>;

std::vector<Position> v{make_positions()};
Position a{1, 5};
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
bool exists = std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator is flawed because it doesn't create a strict order.

Try:

```
bool  operator > (const position&p, const operator&q){
    return((p.x>q.x)|| (p.x==q.x && p.y>q.y));
}
```

**Detailed explanation of the problem:**

With your own implementation:

- the couple {1,4} would not be greater than {1,3} because 1 is not greater than 1, so the logical and will return false.
- But  {1,3} would not either be greater than {1, 4}.

If none of the two couples is greater than the other, they should be in principle equal. As it's not the case, your comparator is not suitable for the binary search.